# Semantic-ui - how to prevent semantic-ui css file from globally taking over other divs / parts of the page / app

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am loading basic semantic-ui.min.css through CDN, ie:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css"></link>
```

However, my page has other divs like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu-in-react"></div>
  <div id="container-for-non-react-stuff"></div>
</div>
```

I would like semantic-ui css to be applied selectively to only:

> `div #menu-in-react`

***and not to***

> div `#container-for-non-react-stuff`

However, right now, by including the *semantic-ui-css file*, it is applying its style to `div #container-for-non-react-stuff` too.

How do I limit the application of *semantic-ui.css* to only specific divs (or exclude from certain divs)?

*Note: I also tried using require('./myDist/semantic.css') using webpack to load the css, but this also ended up in semantic-ui taking over all my divs.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sass, you can nest the entire semantic ui framework inside a parent selector so that it only applies to elements within:

```
#menu-in-react {
  @import 'semantic-ui';
}
```

See here for more info:
https://codepen.io/trey/post/nesting-sass-includes

Do note that you'll have to save the framework css as a local sass partial like `_semantic-ui.scss` in order for this to work, as sass imports will not parse externally hosted resources.

I wouldn't recommend importing the entire framework without cleaning up some of it at least; the framework css includes some dom element styles (ie. `html`, `body`, etc) which would be quite useless when nested in a parent selector.